# Trying to query the nearest places in postgres with the help of user latitude, longitude and places latitude,longitude

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to query the nearest places in postgres with the help of user latitude, longitude and places latitude,longitude with the formula

```
SELECT * FROM place
WHERE acos(sin(0.90987) * sin(latitude) +
      cos(0.9098) * cos(latitude) * cos(0.3675-longitude)) * 6371
      <= 100;
```

But I'm getting error saying:

```
Error: Input is out of range.
```

who can help?

[image: input is out of range]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the coordinates are in radians, there is a typo near the end (the `-longitude` must be outside of the last `cos`)

```sql
SELECT * FROM place 
WHERE 
 acos(
   sin(0.90987)
    *sin(latitude)
   +cos(0.9098)
     *cos(latitude)
     *cos(0.3675)
   -longitude)
*6371<=100
```

That being said, have a look at Postgis, it greatly simplifies spatial queries
`Select * FROM place where st_dwithin(place.geog, my_target_point, 100)`